# GLib commandline option parser - long entry descriptions

Tags: glib, command-line-arguments

I have an application that uses GLib's commandline option parser to handle commandline arguments (as described [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Commandline-option-parser.html)).

What I've found is that the description for each option entry has to be very short - in order to fit within the width of a terminal of standard size (when the application is called with the --help argument). If a description for an option is too long it wraps around, and this looks pretty bad. Is there an accepted way to tidy this up?

For example, here's what part of the help output from my application looks like in an 80 character wide terminal window:

```
Application Options:
  -i, --ip-addr                     Sets the IP address to which the video strea
ms will be sent. If this option is not used then the default IP address of 127.0
.0.1 is used.
  -p, --port                        Sets the port to send the video streams to. 
If not chosen this defaults to 1234.
```

Ideally it would look something like this:

```
Application Options:
  -i, --ip-addr                     Sets the IP address to which the video
                                    streams will be sent. If this option is not
                                    used then the default IP address of
                                    127.0.0.1 is used.
  -p, --port                        Sets the port to send the video streams to.
                                    If not chosen this defaults to 1234.
```

I could just get the above result manually, by working out the required length of each line of my option descriptions. Then I could manually enter newlines and spaces into the strings to get the right indentation. But this seems like a really rough approach, and I'm sure there must be a better and less time-consuming way of formatting the output.

I'm sure this problem must have come up before for others, but I haven't found a solution, does anybody here know of a better way to get nicer formatting?

Comment: File a bug, attach a patch :) and ping the mailinglist to review it – if it is good (and not to much of code-axing, it should go in)

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. At present I am using the ghetto fix of adding spaces. This however is not possible with the argument description (rather than just the description, which is what is printed at the end). If you add newlines to break the argument description the spacing of the proceeding arguments is messed up.